# Return value is null when return value is placed inside the .then function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been trying to fix the following issue for the past two days. I want to create a user and after that return a list as shown below:

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data,context) => {
  try {
    admin.auth().createUser({
      email: "kevin3928@gmail.com"
      password: "a3tbmz"
    }).then((arg) => {
    // a) if I return a variable here it doesn't work
    });
    // b) if I return a variable here it works
  }
});
```

Returning a variable using method b) it works but I need to return the variable using method a). I can't use *async* and *await* because I will receive the following error:

```
 error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

I appreciate it if someone can help me with this, I spent the entire weekend trying to solve this...

Comment: Look up `try..catch` statement

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky Already tried, didn't work.

Comment: You have a syntax error because you don't use correct syntax of `try..catch`. There can't be only `try` block. Look again.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky You're right

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky You were the first one to find the answer, hence if you'd like you can write your solution so that I can accept it.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky - However, your solution only solves one of the two problems in the question.

Comment: (to OP): Please take a look at @JohnHanley's answer. Once they address my comment, the answer becomes perfectly valid, and you could accept it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value from the top-level code of your function, otherwise Cloud Functions may/will terminate your code before the asynchronous operation has completed.

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data,context) => {
  return admin.auth().createUser({
    email: "kevin3928@gmail.com"
    password: "a3tbmz"
  }).then((arg) => {
    return "result";
  }).catch((err) => {
    return err;
  });
});
```

Also see the second code snippet in the documentation on [sending back the result](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result), which does something similar.

Comment: I guess, you've forgot to remove `try {}` wrapper. If not, it's not needed here anyway.

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine - Good catch

Answer (score 0):

try

```
let userCreated = false

exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data,context) => {
  try {
      admin.auth().createUser({
      email: "kevin3928@gmail.com"
      password: "a3tbmz"
    })
userCreated = true

if(userCreated){
  return // the object you wanted to return
}

  } catch(err){
     throw new Error(err)
}
});
```

Comment: **You cannot write any statements in between try, catch and finally blocks**.

Comment: @JohnHanley The indentation is messed up here. Those statements are inside the `try` block

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine - Sloppy code makes QA more challenging.